# How to access the immediate value of a scope variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am sending a `$http` request to save some data to server and getting a response in json. I want to display a android `Toast` like message for success or failure based on the response. 
I declare a scope variable and set it to false at the beginning `$scope.showSuccessToast`. If the message from server is positive I set it to true else to false.

I access the variable `$scope.showSuccessToast` in a javascript function in html  which is also called at the time the server is called to save. I use both `ng-click` and `onclick`.

So in the function if the `$scope.showSuccessToast` is true I show a success message or a fail message. But the first time, even though the response from server is positive, the fail message is shown. So the value probably has not been set to true by the time function accesses the variable. The next time even thought the response is fail I get the success message.

What do I do to make this happen based on the response

```
$scope.showSuccessToast="false";
$scope.saveTollPlaza = function(){
    $http({
        method:'POST',
        url:"http://192.168.1.191:3020/addTollPlaza?PlazaName="+$scope.plazaname+"&PlazaAddress="+$scope.plazaaddress+"&PlazaContactNo="+$scope.plazacontactnumber+"&PlazaLanes="+$scope.plazalane+"&PlazaStatus="+$scope.plazastatus+"&ClientID="+$scope.clientid

    })
    .then(function success(response){
        console.log("success" + response.data.message);
        console.log("http://192.168.1.191:3020/addTollPlaza?PlazaName="+$scope.plazaname+"&PlazaAddress="+$scope.plazaaddress+"&PlazaContactNo="+$scope.plazacontactnumber+"&PlazaLanes="+$scope.plazalane+"&PlazaStatus="+$scope.plazastatus+"&ClientID="+$scope.clientid);
        $scope.plazaname="";
        $scope.plazaaddress="";
        $scope.plazacontactnumber="";
        $scope.plazalane="";
        $scope.plazastatus="";
        $scope.clientid="";

        if(response.data.message == 'added'){
            $scope.showSuccessToast="true";
            console.log("setting true");
        }
        else{
            $scope.showSuccessToast="false";
            console.log("setting false");   
        }
    },function errorCall(response){
        console.log("errorCall"+ response);
    })
```

Script in html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function jShowToast() {
        console.log($('#fullContainerID').scope().showSuccessToast);
        if($('#fullContainerID').scope().showSuccessToast == "true")
        {
            document.getElementById("successFailureDiv").innerHTML="Save Success";
            $('.error').stop().fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400); //fade out after 3 seconds
            $('#fullContainerID').scope().showSuccessToast ="false";
        }
        else{

             document.getElementById("successFailureDiv").innerHTML="Save failed";
            $('.error').stop().fadeIn(400).delay(3000).fadeOut(400);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i also got it to work by using `setTimeout` function in the `jShowToast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is asynchronous. Meaning you can't predict which of the two requests will end first. For that, there are callback functions.

What you should do is call the `toast` from the success callback. That is, use some **angular** library to show the toast, not jquery.

This way, you code will be cleaner and easier for others to understand. Others may have to spend some time before they find your current toast.

So, use [this](https://github.com/jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster) or [this](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/toast) in your success callback.